# Inline Javascript causes Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected token <

Tags: xml, google-chrome, doctype

My sites uses XHTML, strictly sent from server as application/xhtml+xml, on picture are codes with and without error message.

I found error message **Unexpected token <** in Developer Tools on Chrome, which I never seen before. 
(Error message is visible on mobile devices with Chrome).

It seems, that any inline javascript causes this error - but I im sure, that XML code is OK and correct.

[image]

Simpliest code sample **chyba.xhtml**: (if sent as HTML, no error, but I need XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>fake error</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var MY_APLICATION='teplo';
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can somebody help me how to correct ? (or ensure that mistake is on GoogleChrome side ... ver. 65.0.3325.181 official).